# How do I keep ribs and shoulder location from being too deform?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

Is there an easy technique to make the rib cage and shoulders deform more naturally up and down? The sides on my guy's body puff up too much when moving and they look too skinny when relaxed. I also don't want to use manual weight painting because it's annoying having to redo everything if I make some changes to my character's bones, mesh, and other things. And if it involves drivers or shape keys then please tell me what the python code is for them as well as other functions for the bones. [image][image]

Comment: try manual weight painting or use shape keys to fix the deformation (more complex)

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if upper arm weights distributed on the sides of the chest too strongly. So when the arm moves, those vertices will follow it. You could weight paint it there to reduce the arm influence. You could first check that autonormalize and x-mirror is turned on in options on the right. Then with a Mix brush, Weight; 0.000, Radius: enough, Strength: turn the slider down very low and paint to take away some of the weight then paint and test, paint and test until it's right. Or you could select those vertices on the chest only, with the upper arm bone highlighted and use the levels tool to reduce the strength of them there.